# Prove that if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\rightarrow 0$, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}f(x) \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

If $f(x)$ is a function that grows more slowly than $g(x)$, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ approaches $0$ as $x$ increases.

Ok, so can anyone prove that:

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}f(x) \rightarrow 0?$$

I have the intuition this follows but I can’t prove it.

Comment: What about $f(x)= \sqrt x, g(x)=x$ ?

Comment: if $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 2x$ then the quotient tends to $1/2$, so even your first sentence is not true. You have to be more specific when you say $f$ 'grows more slowly' than $g$.

Answer (score 2):

**Expanded from Mason's comment**

---

It is false.

*Counter example:* Let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=x^2$. Then,

$$f'(x)=1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad g'(x)=2x.$$

Clearly, $f'(x)<g'(x)$.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x^2}\cdot x = 1 \color{red}{\ne 0}.$$

Comment: Ok, thanks: in that case, how much more slowly must f(x) grow than g(x) for this to be true?

Comment: @cathalcom There are infinitely many $f$ and $g$ (satisfying the condition mentioned in the post) that disprove $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}f(x) \to 0$$

Comment: If you take, e.g., $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2x$, then the limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$ of $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}f(x)$$ is $\infty$ (does not exist)

Comment: Yes thanks I can see that now - but what I’m trying to identify is under what circumstances will it be satisfied that if f(x)/g(x) -> 0, then f(x)/g(x))*f(x) -> 0 ?     Eg if the growth rate of f(x) is less than half of g(x)?

Comment: For the limit to approach something less than $1$, $(f(x))^2 < g(x)$ as $x$ as infinitely large.

Comment: I see, thanks- so if (f(x))^2 < g(x), then f(x)/g(x))*(f(x)) -> 0? If I have that right can you explain why it’s true (ie prove it?) thx!!

Comment: @cathalcom You should ask a new question for that, something like, $``$How slow should be the relative growth of $f$ with respect to $g$ for $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot f(x) \to 0."$$

Comment: I'm ***not*** saying that $f(x)^2<g(x)\implies \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot f(x) \to 0 \text{ for large $x$.}$ I am saying that if $f(x)^2<g(x)$, then $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot f(x) < 1.$$

Comment: Ok thank for all your help Aditya! That may actually be all I need. Can you show why this is the case? (Why it must approach something less than 1?)

Comment: Consider this: $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2x^2$. Then, $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{2x^2}\cdot x = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: If $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^4$, then $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x^4}\cdot x=0$$

Comment: Thank you Aditya!

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Take your favorite increasing function $u$ going to $+\infty$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$, and set $f=u$ and $g=u^2$. Then $f/g=1/u$ goes to $0$
, so $f$ increases more slowly than $g$ (whatever it could really mean), then $(f/g)f$ is the constant function $1$.

Comment: Shouldn't the function be $f$ instead of $u$?

Comment: @aditya: $u$ is a function

Comment: This answer has an issue: if $g=u^2$ and $u\to0$, then $f/g\to\infty$.

Comment: sorry, it is a misprint. I meant going to $+\infty$. I'm editing the answer.